# How to run copy of the app running on '/' on '/someurl' as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

Let's say I have a site like Digg running on `bookmarks.com` and want to create `bookmarks.com/girls` which shares all the routes, but all the links point to `/girls/<something>` instead of just `/<something>`.

Without changing all the links in views, I would like to modify `routes.rb` to do something like this:

```
all_routes = lambda {
  ...
}

scope '/girls', &all_routes, constraint: { |r| r.session[:subsite] == girls }
scope '/', &all_routes
```

However I am stuck with trial and error and haven't been able to come up with a solution.

**Bonus points**: how would I route this, if I had dynamic multiple sub-sites?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by subclassing your Rails app, and then mounting it using [Rack.mount](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-mount) in your routes

```
mount AnotherRailsApp, :at => "/something"
```

Alternatively, you could use a rackup file, so in config.ru:

```
map "/" do
  run RailsApp::Application
end

map "/something" do
  run AnotherRailsApp::Application
end
```

However, with either approach, I'm not sure Rails' helper methods for URLs will be able to generate valid URLs when mounted at "/something", and you're probably going to get some interesting issues with your data too, unless you have one db per app.

Comment: Sounded good, but looks like Rails doesn't like this. (`You cannot inherit from a Rails::Application child (RuntimeError)`)